# Can't get json_encode to work with database entry

Tags: php, json, mysqli

No matter what I do, I can't seem to get json_encode to work on returned results from my `fr` column.

Here is an export of my table:  mctrivia.com/language.zip

I set everything to utf8mb4 as suggested by my googling this problem but no luck.

If $language is 'en' and $fileID=1 this works.
If $language is 'fr' and $fileID=1 this fails.

Either way the print_r gives proper results. The echo is showing null with fr.

```
    //get list of words in current language file
    $query='SELECT `key`,`' . $language . '` FROM `language` WHERE `file`=' . $fileID;
    $stmtGetWords = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmtGetWords->bind_result($wordID,$text);
    $stmtGetWords->execute();
    $wordList=array();
      while ($stmtGetWords->fetch()) {
        $wordList[$wordID]=$text;
    }
    print_r($wordList);
    $stmtGetWords->close();

    //create json file data
    $fileData=json_encode($wordList);
    echo '<br>'. $fileData . '<br>';
```

Results from language en:

```
Array ( [lang] => English [subPage1Intro] => Welcome to sub page 1. ) 
{"lang":"English","subPage1Intro":"Welcome to sub page 1."}
```

Results from language fr:

```
Array ( [lang] => Fran�ais [subPage1Intro] => Bienvenue � sous page 1. )
```

Comment: Could you please add the neccessary information within the question? In this case the result of `print_r`.

Comment: Results added to question.

Comment: How did you get those two result? Print_r of what variable ?  Also what is this method doing "$stmtGetWords->bind_result($wordID,$text);"

Comment: JSON must be utf-8 encoded, the french text doesn't seems to be utf8. That's why you `can't get it to work`

Comment: @KhorneHoly: Was just about to say the same thing. It can't work if the ç isn't properly loaded or displayed!

Comment: It loads and displays properly in phpMyAdmin.  How can I make a form field send me utf8 then?

Comment: `var_dump(json_last_error())`. don't assume the encoding succeeded.

Comment: The way the french appears broken is a sure sign that it is ***not*** UTF-8 encoded. Check the duplicate for everything that can be set to UTF-8, most importantly everything database related. If still not solved, post details about your database connection here.

Comment: thanks.  seems you can't enter values via phpMyAdmin.  Created a page to enter data with `accept-charset="UTF-8"` in the form tag and it all works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Your french text doesn't contain valid JSON, because it's not UTF-8! You can find more information on the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_portability_issues).

As soon as your JSON contains proper UTF-8, it'll work.